# Преобразовать массив строк из статического в динамический

Tags: c, строки

нашел [код](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15472359/1015062)

```
char string[]=  "abc/qwe/jkh";
char *array[10];
int i=0;

array[i] = strtok(string,"/");

while(array[i]!=NULL)
{
   array[++i] = strtok(NULL,"/");
}
```

И задался я целью сделать его более универсальным т.е. добавить динамическое выделение памяти.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *string = "Value1,123,Value2,456,Value3,789,"; // запятая в конце необходима
char **array_of_strings = NULL; // указатель на указатель строк
int i = 0;
long comma_counter = 0;
int eachLine = 0;

// считаем количество запятых, чтобы понять сколько нам нужно памяти

for (i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {
    if (string[i] == ',') {
        comma_counter++;
    }
}
printf("Commas counted: %d\n", (int)comma_counter);

array_of_strings = malloc(comma_counter * sizeof(char*)); // выделяем столько сколько насчитали 

if (array_of_strings == NULL) {
    printf("Memory allocation failed!");
    exit(1);
}
```

И вот первая проблема. strok возвращает указатель, и мне его нужно записать в array_of_strings позиция 0.

Как записать строку в array_of_strings[0]?

```
---> = strtok(string, ",");
--->printf("%s\n", array_of_strings[eachLine]);

--->while(*array_of_strings) // дальше надо делать снова вызов выделения памяти
--->{
--->    array_of_strings = malloc();
--->    array_of_strings[++i] = strtok(NULL, ",");
--->    array_of_strings++;
--->}


// ну а это будущий вывод строк на экран
for (i = 0; i < comma_counter; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", array_of_strings[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример разбивки строк есть [здесь](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/?kw=strtok). Часто пользуюсь этим ресурсом.
Что-то такое может быть:

```
char string[] = "Value1,123,Value2,456,Value3,789,";
int comma_counter=6;

char *pCh;
char **array_of_strings=(char**)malloc(sizeof(pCh)*comma_counter);
//переменная string изменится
int k=0;
char * pch= strtok(string, ",");
while(pch!=NULL)
{
    array_of_strings[k] = (char*)malloc(strlen(pch)*sizeof(char)+1);
    if (array_of_strings[k]==NULL) exit (1);
    strcpy(array_of_strings[k], pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, ",");
    k++;
    if(k==comma_counter) pch=NULL;
}

printf ("%s \n %s", array_of_strings[0],array_of_strings[comma_counter-1]);

//не забывайте освобождать память
for(int i=0;i<comma_counter;++i)
{
 free(array_of_strings[i]); 
}
free(array_of_strings);
```

Comment: Или можно вызывать уже существующую [strdup](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup)

Comment: Падает прямо  тут char * pch= strtok(string, ","); Если поменять char *string; на char *string[] то на этой строке не падает, падает дальше.

Comment: @GarfieldCat Забыл первоначально добавить строчку pch = strtok (NULL, ",");. Попробуйте определить string, как у меня в коде.

Comment: @GarfieldCat Маленькая оплошность. Ещё поправил.

Comment: @MindCleaner Да, но все равно падает.

Comment: @GarfieldCat Привожу последнюю правку кода. Я его откомпилировал, запустил и он мне корректно выдал первое и последнее значение: "Value1" и "789".